# How can we prove that assuming point masses at the midpoints of the sides gives the proper result for the triangular plate?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

https://youtu.be/6qApC7YAQZs (4mins 30s - 5 mins 30s), in this video Sir explains how to use the point masses half way along the sides of a triangle, to calculate the moment of inertia of a triangular plate.

But how can we prove that assuming point masses at the midpoints of the sides gives the proper result for the triangular plate? Key idea needed?

Comment: This question needs to be edited so it is self-contained and the title accurately describes the content of the question.

Comment: I did a bit @Emilio_Pisanty

Comment: The title refers to "the video". Nothing is substantially improved thus far.

Comment: Now  is it ok Sir?

Comment: Not at all. Look at other questions before attempting further edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:  If you look into

1. The moment of inertia of a triangle through the 'centroid'
2. The parallel axis theorem

and use fact that

3. The co-ordinate of the centroid is $(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}, \frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3})$

Then maybe you'll prove the result used in the video.

Comment: It could be a good question for Maths SE.

Comment: Thanks i got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce a continuous mass to its centre-of-mass point when the extend of the object isn't important.

When dealing purely with inertial forces and gravity and more, then the rotational effects of all points on either side of the centre-of-mass will typically cancel out. Then their locations do not matter, and it is much easier to model the object as just a point.

Comment: The video is doing something diff. , pls once watch it Sir

Comment: @Orion_Pax I was answering to what was mentioned in the text of your question. Unfortunately I do not have the time to look through the video. If you describe the question, then I can have a go at it

Comment: I see sry for not clearing very fine